# removing authorization access to addressbook and calendar

Tags: macos, mac

While installing / running the first time, I authorized the app to have access to addressbook and calendar.  How do I go about to revoke that permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose which apps can access Contact & Calendar data from
System Prefs > Security & Privacy > Privacy

Check or uncheck each app

[image]